# spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect. ¿¿Problema de version?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Parece que el problema principal está en la carga de la clase *org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect*. La excepción *java.lang.ClassNotFoundException* indica que la clase no puede ser encontrada, lo que sugiere que puede haber un problema con la dependencia de Hibernate o con la configuración de las dependencias en el proyecto.

**application.properties**

```java
server.port=8083
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_springboot
spring.datasource.username=root 
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect <<Este es el problema
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
```

Tengo estas dependencias: Carpeta(Maven Dependencies)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tambien adjunto todas las dependencias en el archivo pom.xml**

```java
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Derrepente me falta agregar algo no lo se, pero entiendo que el problema esta con las versiones de hibernate o algo asi.

Comment: ¿Has probado lo que indican [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74580109/2553194)?

Comment: Asi ese, entendi que cambie esto `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect 
` por esto `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect `, pero sigo con el problema

Answer (score 1):

**Lo solucione asi**:

*Primero intente agregar esta dependencia*

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>6.2.22.Final</version> 
</dependency>
```

**No sirvio de nada.**
Lo unico que me sirvio es cambiar

esto

`spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect`

por esto

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`

Asi como tambien **sin usar ninguna** de las 2, tambien me funciono.